# Pluck in the intro Kensei Ummet ozcan

Tags: sound-design, distortion

The track can be heard here:

The sound has high harmonics, maybe like a waveshaper? Certainly regular distortion is overkill.

The specific pluck starts at the intro 1...2,3 - 1...2,3 - 1...2,3 - 1,2,3,4 and repeat

I want to know what waveform, distortion creates those harmonics. Maybe someone here recognizes the sound?

Attemt 1: [kensei pluck sien](https://clyp.it/xilqevoa) Note: no additional fx, eq, compression or widening tools. Just the synth.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick analysis:** It has a cycle running through it, like a cricket's chirp. Maybe tremolo, but probably part of the wave shaping process- a cycled wave, maybe originally a much lower pitched looping sound. Overall distortion effect sounds like a subtle Bitcrusher.

It's very wide, spatially. Envelope has a Fast decay, low sustain, no release.

Everything is heavily compressed.

Comment: I noticed the cyle you mention. Like an FM modulation of an oscillator by another oscillator? Any idea which waveform? The lower in pitch sounds possible. That creates the higher harmonics right? 

Any bitcrusher in particular?